# Deleted file on MacOS still occupying space

Tags: macos

1. I download a large file, a 20GB DMG.
2. Soon after, I ran out of space, I used the system information app to delete large files, including the 20 GB DMG.
3. The System Information app crashed during this process, and I had to restart my laptop.
4. Ever since, the System Manager still shows the DMG as occupying 20GB of space, but I cannot "open in Finder" or delete. Both the buttons do nothing.
5. I tried searching for the said file, but found nothing.
6. I have verified that the trash is empty.

I want to reclaim the 20GB of space that has been locked out, *without* having to format my disk again.

[image: Storage Manager on Mac ( About -> Storage -> Manage ) still shows Dota 2 occupying 20.44GB]

Selecting Dota 2 and clicking on "Show in Finder" does nothing.
Looking for the file via `ls -la` does not show the file.

[image: Applications folder does not show the file]
Applications folder does not show the file

[image: Trash is empty]
Trash is empty

[image: File type has changed to APPS_APPLS after updating to Big Sur, but no resolution to the problem.]

File type has changed to `APPS_APPLS` after updating to Big Sur, but no resolution to the problem.

Comment: What is System Manager, can you add a screenshot showing details? Do the 20GB also show up in free disk space (so ist the free disk space about 20 GB lower than before the download)?

Comment: I still wonder if the 20 GB are actually occupied or if you just see an inconsistent view here. Assuming you did install Dota before deleting it, can you open Terminal, run `ls -ld /Applications/Dot*` and report the result?

Comment: I see no files found when running `ls -ld /Applications/Dot*`. Moreover, adding the size of all the other files in `~/Applications` comes to ~ 41 GB, while the folder itself is occupying ~60 GB.

I have some new information though, not sure if it helps. I upgraded to the Big Sur Beta, and the file type now shows up as `APPS_APPLS`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk space not freed up after deleting files and emptying Trash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44203/disk-space-not-freed-up-after-deleting-files-and-emptying-trash)

Answer (score 2):

You need to empty your Trash. When you delete a file that just moves it to the trash. To free up space you must empty the trash.

Then you have to suspect that your spotlight process that feeds these displays is stuck. Log out of your account and then restart the mac.

See if you can reveal in finder the app below the one in question.

If the app in question is stuck, rebooting to recovery and then running disk utility to check / repair the filesystem would be prudent. Making a backup also would be prudent if this is a sign of directory damage. You can fix that easily with an erase / install - then load back the apps from backup.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention this in my comment, but I have also verified that the trash is empty. Also, since the file was deleted via the storage manager, it doesn't really go to the trash anyway. I think the app crashing has left the file in some weird state, where it is still occupying space, but not visible anywhere.

Comment: @NavedKhan I’ve added substantial information here - your system is clearly not behaving  well - let’s get a restart and check.

Answer (score 0):

Apple menu > Restart. When the Apple logo appears, hold shift and then you'll boot into safe mode.

Check the free space there.

Apple menu > Restart. Don't hold anything this time. You'll boot into normal mode.

https://support.apple.com/HT201262