# Macintosh HD - Data First aid fail - storage problem

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, storage

I recently started to have kernel panic errors and my macbook pro 2019 crashed several times, this started to worry me and the first thing which I noticed was that my storage was pretty full (maybe 20gb available).

I then hard heartedly deleted several 100GB of data, however noticed that the storage space never expanded.

I ran the disk utility first aid in the Recovery mode (during restart CMD + R), however didn't manage to solve the problem (below is picture which has been take in normal mode).

Any advice how to proceed from here or how to fix my hard drive?

[image: first aid fail]

Edit: Found this one, but this looks pretty radical to try out, looking for other options:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406063/438490

Answer (score 1):

I would boot to recovery and re-run disk utility as instructed.

Since you did that and it fails, I back up the drive and test the backup and do an erase install.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/erase-and-reinstall-macos-mh27903/mac

Unless you wanted to open a support case and have them look at the logs, this is what happens when the utility can't guarantee data integrity. It's often not even a hardware error, but it could so the part about being sure your backup is complete and works is important.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the erase install? maybe there is a pointer / link on how to do it properly?

Comment: I edited the answer to include apple link on erase install @N3Ar

Comment: thanks, I will look into this and try it out perhaps over the weekend, seems scary but doable!